# Check if table exists in informix and postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, informix

I want to check if a table exists before I create a new one. I am using the following method:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, getTableNamePattern(), null);
if (rs != null) {
    if (rs.next()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It was doing fine for databases like oracle, sqlserver, and mysql. However, it does not work on informix and postgresql. Anyone has a good suggestion? Thanks

Comment: `create table if not exists <tablename>...` will do it in postgres.

Comment: lower case/upper case problem? Postgres stores the table names in lower case, so you need to pass the patter as lower case as well.

Comment: I don't think Java code ought to be doing such checks.  Either the schema exists and has been initialized properly by an admin prior to launching the Java application or it wasn't.

Comment: thanks for the hints, the reason I did not use "if exists" in a statement is because I want to provide the users a method to check the table before they create a new one. So basically there will be two methods. if (!tableExisted()) createTable(); something like that

Comment: Informix also has `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, and also stores table names in lower-case unless you really force its hand very hard.

Comment: Thanks @Bill and a_horse_with_no_name, all the answers are good. I take the IF NOT EXISTS as the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it on PostgreSQL and it works just fine.

The problem is probably in your search pattern. Here are some things to keep in mind:

- `_` is used as a wildcard for a single letter, `%` as a wildcard for an arbitrary string.
- The pattern is case sensitive, and table names default to lower case in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Should I apply % as the parameter and set it as default when I do the search?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Use `t%` to search for all tables whose names start with `t`, but don't expect that it matches an uppercase `T` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also take Jonathan Leffler's answer. I get it to work after I set the incoming table name to lowercase.